# Handling navigation events

Tags: dotnetbrowser

I want to inject functionality following any navigation of pages within a DotNetBrowser instance.

I've tried hooking the following events, but they all only fire on the first load and not after each navigation event.

```
FinishedLoadingFrameEvent 
DocumentLoadedInMainFrameEvent
```

I've also tried hooking the onLoad DOM event against the document element using the DOM events API.

Comment: The `FinishLoadingFrameEvent` is fired for each frame loaded on the web page, even after the page is reloaded: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45642333/dotnetbrowser-finishloadingframeevent-multiple-use